# How do trigger a rerender based on a timer but only on a specific component in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, react-hooks

I have a component that renders relative time

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useReducer } from 'react'
import { Text, TextProps } from 'react-native';
import { formatDistanceToNow } from 'date-fns';
type MomentTextProps = Omit<TextProps, 'children'> & {
  date: Date | number;
  pollTimeMs?: number;
}

export function MomentText({
  date,
  pollTimeMs = 60000,
  ...props }: MomentTextProps): JSX.Element {
  const [formatted, update] = useReducer(
    () => formatDistanceToNow(Date.now()),
    formatDistanceToNow(Date.now())
  );
  const timeoutRef = useRef<ReturnType<typeof setTimeout>>();
  function doUpdate() {
    update();
    timeoutRef.current = setTimeout(update, pollTimeMs);
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    doUpdate();
    return () => {
      clearTimeout(timeoutRef.current!);
    };
  });

  return <Text {...props}>{formatted}</Text>
}
```

Which works, but seems overkill that I am creating so many timeouts, I was wondering if there's a way of doing this via a "React context" but only rerender this one specific child.

The way I am thinking of it (as I type this) is to have a `subscribe/notify` hook like this...

```
/**
 * This hook provides a simple subscription semantic to React components.
 */
export function useSubscription<T = unknown>(): SubscriptionManager<T> {
  const subscribersRef = useRef<((data: T) => void)[]>([]);
  function subscribe(fn: (data: T) => void) {
    subscribersRef.current.push(fn);
    return () => {
      subscribersRef.current = subscribersRef.current.filter(
        (subscription) => !Object.is(subscription, fn)
      );
    };
  }
  function notify(data: T) {
    subscribersRef.current.forEach((fn) => fn(data));
  }
  function useSubscribeEffect(fn: (data: T) => void) {
    useEffect(() => subscribe(fn), []);
  }
  return { subscribe, notify, useSubscribeEffect };
}
```

and have a `useRef` and `useEffect` that will call `notify` on the `MomentText` component.

Seems quite overkill but not really sure which is worse.

The first approach is easy to understand, but may be a performance hit

The second is a bit more complicated, but the usage is isolated since it's just a context requirement and everything else can be handled by subscriptions within the component.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the idea I had with the context would indeed work, but I had to create a new hook called `useClock` which is implemented below.

```
import { useEffect, useRef } from "react";

import { SubscriptionManager, useSubscription } from "../useSubscription";

/**
 * time to next full minute from the date
 * @param date
 * @returns milliseconds to next full minute from date
 */
function timeToNextFullMinute(date: number): number {
  return 60000 - (date % 60000);
}
/**
 * This hook notifies the subscribers with the current date.  This
 * is useful for updating components that show moment in time without
 * a full rerender of the tree.
 *
 * It notifies at the following points:
 * - useEffect
 * - first minute at zero seconds
 * - every minute after at zero seconds
 *
 * However, due to the performance of the device, this may not be acurate.
 *
 * @returns subscription manager
 */
export function useClock(): SubscriptionManager<number> {
  const { subscribe, notify, useSubscribeEffect } = useSubscription<number>();
  const timeoutRef = useRef<ReturnType<typeof setTimeout>>();

  function doNotify() {
    notify(Date.now());
    timeoutRef.current = setTimeout(doNotify, timeToNextFullMinute(Date.now()));
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    doNotify();
    return () => {
      // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-non-null-assertion
      clearTimeout(timeoutRef.current!);
    };
  }, []);

  return { subscribe, notify, useSubscribeEffect };
}
```

My context would then provide the `useSubscribeEffect` specific to the `useClock` hook which I then use from `MomentText` which would be:

```
type MomentTextProps = Omit<TextProps, "children"> & {
  on: Date | number;
};
export function MomentText({ on, ...props }: MomentTextProps): JSX.Element {
  const { useClockSubscribeEffect } = useDevhausUI();
  const { formatRelativeToNow } = useLocalization();
  const [text, setText] = useState(formatRelativeToNow(on));

  useClockSubscribeEffect(() => setText(formatRelativeToNow(on)));

  return <Text {...props}>{text}</Text>;
}
```

With this approach, the timeout is managed in the `useClock()` hook and it is part of a context so there's not too many running around.

Source and test available at https://github.com/trajano/react-hooks-tests/tree/master/src/useClock